# Can't Add Mapbox hosted DigitalGlobe Basemap in QGIS 3.2

Tags: mapbox, satellite

I'm having trouble viewing a Digital Globe base map in QGIS. I'm following Mapbox's instructions from their API
https://mapsapidocs.digitalglobe.com/v2.0/docs/tiles (bottom section that describes connecting with WMTS). In QGIS 3.2.0, I add new WMS/WMTS layer (“Layer” -> “Add Layer” -> “Add WMS/WMTS Layer…”), and I add the new layer with the URL with my own Mapbox public token (i.e. https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/digitalglobe/cinvynyut001db4m6xwd5cz1f/wmts?access_token=MY_TOKEN) and I hit connect, but I keep getting the error message:

Failed to download capabilities:
Download of capabilities failed: Error transferring https:
https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/digitalglobe/cinvynyut001db4m6xwd5cz1f/wmts?access_token=pk.ey...bunch of token characters...=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

-server replied: Not Found

My token starts with pk.ey and a bunch of random characters so I'm sure its the right one.  I'm using the mapbox Pay-as-you-go plan, and I haven't added any money to the account. Do I need to pay for this service? I thought Mapbox offered some limited views of Digital Globe images for free.  Or maybe it's a technical problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think those DigitalGlobe services require a DigitalGlobe access token, not a Mapbox access token. See https://mapsapidocs.digitalglobe.com/docs/access-tokens

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but the DG tokens required paying for access. I found another way to do it in QGIS using add XYZ map tiles.